# Validate Telegram user details like phone number, id, name, etc

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

We have our app which is working inside the Telegram app and we need to create a user in Firebase using the JWT token. To create the JWT token, we need to verify users' details.

Is there any way to validate users' details like name, phone, id, etc., on the backend from Telegram using `access_hash` or any other token?

Comment: What do you mean by validate? The data Telegram provides can be used as validation?

Comment: Anyone can send the data to API. To validate those requests, we need to confirm from Telegram whether the request comes with valid data or not.

Comment: No, only the one with the bot token can send data to the telegram api. The updates in eg `getUpdates` can't be validated.

Comment: then is there any way to get user details based on userId or access_hash?

Comment: Using the bot api? Don't think there is.